# jQTouch: How to make phone number link trigger phone app?

Tags: iphone, jqtouch

I am using jQTouch to create a web app that acts like a native iPhone app. I am trying to duplicate the functionality of the Contacts app. I have created a list view that allows you to tap on a name and see their contact info.

On a normal web page, phone numbers are turned into links that trigger the Phone app when tapped. I want to do the same thing, but I can't seem to figure out how. iPhone is not doing it automatically.

How can I get my phone numbers to trigger the Phone app when tapped?

Comment: Have you tried this: `<a href="tel:1234 5678">1234 5678</a>`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably way over this issue 2.5 years down the line, but I had the same problem and found that if I stopPropagation on the element it works. So in your case some Zepto or JQuery:

```
$('a').tap(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
 })
```

works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to mark up the number using the ['tel' URL Scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html#GENERAL-DIAL_A_PHONE_NUMBER_FROM_A_WEBPAGE_ON_IPHONE)

eg `<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can manually link them, like this:

```
<a href="tel:+416362610">
   Call me my love you can call me any day or night 
</a>
```